# C++: Why is the created vector not passing to the next set of for loops?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, parameter-passing

I have it so that the user defines the size of the vector and then a vector is filled. Then that vector is sorted using bubble sort (homework assignment). However, when the "sorted" vector is displayed, there are different numbers in it than what were in the original creation. How do I first create the vector, display it, then sort it and display it??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    double average=0.0;
    int median = 0;
    double size = 0.0;
    int i=0;

    cout<<"Vector Length?: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> data;
    srand(time(NULL));


    //Filling vector
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        data.push_back(rand()%10+1);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vector: "<< data[i]<<endl;
    }

    size = data.size();

    //Sorting
    void bubbleSort(vector<int> & data);
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<size -1 - k; i++)
            {   
                if (data[i] > data[i +1])
                {
                    int temp = data[i];
                    data[i] = data[i + 1];
                    data[i + 1] = temp;
                }
                cout<<"Sorted vector: "<< data[i]<<endl;
            } 
        }               
    }
```

Comment: `for (auto i : data) { std::cout << i << ' ';}`

Comment: You have declared a function `void bubbleSort(vector<int>& data)` inside your main. What were you trying to do with it?

Comment: Why are you printing the vector elements inside the sorting loop? You should do that after you've finished sorting.

Comment: Barmar is correct, you need to move the printing outside of the sorting loops. Your current program does not print the actual sorted vector. The number of elements printed may not even be the number of elements in the vector with the current design.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.

@Phantom I was trying to create and use a function. I thought functions could be created inside int main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off:

1. make sure to include all necessary header files, e.g. `stdlib.h` for your used `rand()` function.
2. get rid of all unused variables, like `average`, `median` and `size`.
3. declare your `bubbleSort` function outside of `main` function, and add additional checkup code to prevent sort if list has not more than one element.

The sort problem is related to this code snippet of yours:

```
for (int i = 0; i<size -1 - k; i++) { ... }
```

> Simply remove -1

To fix your sort problem, and for better output, use following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(vector<int>& data)
{
    if(data.size() <= 1)
        return;

    for(int i=1; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<data.size()-i; j++)
        {
            if(data.at(j) > data.at(j+1))
            {
                int temp = data.at(j+1);
                data.at(j+1) = data.at(j);
                data.at(j) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    vector<int> data;

    cout << "Vector Length?: ";
    cin >> n;

    // Filling vector
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        data.push_back(rand()%10+1);

    cout << "Vector: ";
    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
        cout << data.at(i) << ", ";

    // Sorting
    bubbleSort(data);

    cout << endl << "Sorted Vector: ";
    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
        cout << data.at(i) << ", ";

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: So with the `<stdlib.h>` you don't need to use `srand(time(NULL)`?

Comment: @Aaron no but `<stdlib.h>` is necessary to make `rand()` and `srand()` available. since you want to have random chosen numbers each time you execute your code, simple add this code snippet of yours before executing the `rand()` function: `srand(time(0))`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are planning to define function void bubbleSort(vector & data) later you need to declare it before calling it.\

   `void bubbleSort(vector<int> & data);
     int main()
     {
               // Here your code
                bubbleSort(data);
               //Here your code 
     }`
2. You need to define variables only just before you need it. And if you declare and  never use it, you will get unused variable warnings. So better you can comment all these variables. You can un-comment whenever you need.

   `//double average=0.0;
   //int median = 0;`
3. You should call your function `bubbleSort()` from  `main()` as follows:

   ```
   bubbleSort(data);
   ```
4. You are not using the iterator indexes properly to sort the elements of vector. If you change your function bubbleSort as follows it will work

`//Sorting
void bubbleSort(vector<int> & data)
{
             int size = data.size();
            for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<size -1 ; i++)
                {

                    if (data[i] > data[k])
                    {
                        int temp = data[i];
                        data[i] = data[k];
                        data[k] = temp;
                    }
                    //cout<<"Sorted vector: "<< data[i]<<endl;
                } 
            }

}`

**complete program for your reference:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

 //Sorting
 void bubbleSort(vector<int> & data)
    {
         int size = data.size();
        for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<size -1 ; i++)
            {   
                if (data[i] > data[k])
                {
                    int temp = data[i];
                    data[i] = data[k];
                    data[k] = temp;
                }
                //cout<<"Sorted vector: "<< data[i]<<endl;
            } 
        }               
    }   

int main()
{
    int n;
    //double average=0.0;
    //int median = 0;
    //double size = 0.0;
    //int i=0;

    cout<<"Vector Length?: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
   // int n =10;
    vector<int> data;
    srand(time(NULL));


    //Filling vector
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        data.push_back(rand()%10+1);
    }
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vector: "<< data[i]<<endl;
    }


    bubbleSort(data);
    std::cout<<"sorted vector"<<"\n";
     for (unsigned int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vector: "<< data[i]<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I wish I could also mark your answer as the best, it was very helpful! Thank you!!

Further learning: Is it possible to create and then use a function inside int main? Or must they always be used in the way you show above?

Comment: @Aron As I specified in answer, you cannot define a function inside another   function even not inside main(). You can only call one function from another.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

void printVector(vector<int> & data)
{
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vector: "<< data[i]<<endl;
    }
}

//Sorting
void bubbleSort(vector<int> & data);
{
    size = data.size();
    for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<size -1 - k; i++)
        {   
            if (data[i] > data[i +1])
            {
                int temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[i + 1];
                data[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        } 
    }               
}   

int main()
{
    int n;
    double average=0.0;
    int median = 0;
    double size = 0.0;
    int i=0;

    cout<<"Vector Length?: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> data;
    srand(time(NULL));


    //Filling vector
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        data.push_back(rand()%10+1);
    }
    printVector(data);
    bubbleSort(data);
    printVector(data);

}
```